# Zeus under Rubymine runs routing specs but not model specs

Tags: rspec, rubymine, zeus

Rubymine 6.3.2

This command works from console:
`/Users/batman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby /Users/batman/work/marvin/marvin/bin/zeus rspec /Users/batman/work/marvin/marvin/spec/models --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --pattern **/*_spec.rb`

But this command under Rubymine:
`/Users/batman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/batman/work/marvin/marvin/bin/zeus rspec /Users/batman/work/marvin/marvin/spec/models --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --pattern **/*_spec.rb`
throws:

```
/Users/batman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@marvin/gems/zeus-0.15.1/bin/zeus:2:in ``': No such file or directory - uname (Errno::ENOENT)
from /Users/batman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@marvin/gems/zeus-0.15.1/bin/zeus:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/batman/work/marvin/marvin/bin/zeus:16:in `load'
from /Users/batman/work/marvin/marvin/bin/zeus:16:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

on the other hand:

`/Users/batman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/batman/work/marvin/marvin/bin/zeus rspec /Users/batman/work/marvin/marvin/spec/routing --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --pattern **/*_spec.rb`
works perfect

Second thing:
Rubymine rerun all specs instead of rerun specs that changed it infuriates

Thank you